# Writing Formal version of a statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

How do i write the formal version of the following statement: No integer is both non-positive and non-negative unless it is the zero integer.

Should i split the statement into the form $p$ unless $q$ with the predicate domain as $\mathbb{Z}$?

I will appreciate a detailed explanation on the interpretation of the statement in its predicate statement form instead of only providing the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Consider an *integer* $n$ whatever: we have that $\lnot ( n \le 0 \land n \ge 0) \lor n=0$. Note that "unless" is (usually) "or".

Comment: The left part translates: "the number $n$ is not both non-positive and non-negative" that is true for every number except $0$. Thus, we add the right part to take care of the $0$ case.

Comment: What we have obtained is true for every integer $n$, and thus we can universally quantify it.

Comment: The last step is a propositional transformation: $\lnot p \lor q$ is equiv to $p \to q$, as suggested by the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use the following trick when dealing with an 'unless':  substitute 'if not'.

That is, 'P unless Q' becomes 'P if not Q'

Applied to your statement, we thus get: 'No integer is both non-positive and non-negative if it is not the zero integer'

Also, 'No P is Q' is the same as 'All P is not Q' or 'Any P is not Q', and thus we get:

'Any integers is not both non-positive and non-negative if it is not the zero integer'

Which translates to:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z} (x \not =0 \rightarrow \neg (\neg x > 0 \land \neg x < 0))$$

Comment: Thanks, my mistake was that i thought "No integer" applies to the entire conditional statement (both hypothesis and conclusion).

Comment: So,  the statement can be first rewritten as "Any integer is either positive or negative unless it is the zero integer".

Comment: @LittleRookie Yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 0):

$(\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}):n\geqslant0\wedge n\leqslant0\implies n=0$